# Is there a way to use styled-components in a React app, without renaming all existing components?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, styled-components

I want to refactor an existing React app and add `styled-components`.
The issue is that the only way I'm seeing this working is if I rename all existing functional components, create new styled ones, and name them with the old names, so that when I use them to build the App, it looks the same.

I renamed this component from `Button` to `DefaultButton`:

```
class DefaultButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button className={this.props.className}>
      {this.props.text}
    </button>;
  }
}
```

And then created the styled component with the old name:

```
let Button = styled(DefaultButton)`
  color: ${props => props.theme.buttonStyles.color};
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.buttonStyles.backgroundColor};
`;

Button.defaultProps = {
  theme: {
    buttonStyles: {
      color: '#000',
      backgroundColor: '#ccc'
    }
  }
};

export default Button;
```

And now I can use it as before:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={mytheme}>
  <div className="App">
    <Button text="Give me an answer here"></Button>
  </div>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Is there a way to add the new styles and not rename all existing components?
Any improvement/advice to the code above is welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to rename the components, you can simply write it like

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button className={this.props.className}>
      {this.props.text}
    </button>;
  }
}

Button = styled(Button)`
  color: ${props => props.theme.buttonStyles.color};
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.buttonStyles.backgroundColor};
`;

Button.defaultProps = {
  theme: {
    buttonStyles: {
      color: '#000',
      backgroundColor: '#ccc'
    }
  }
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: I tried this but get an error saying "Button is read-only"